# How to remove leading zero from string in SAPUI5 applications in XML view?

Tags: sapui5

I have an integer number in SAPDB but it has to be store as NUMERIC for some reason and numeric values are stored as string in SAP DB.

Thus OData service returns `0000000001` instead of `1`.

SO the question is how can I remove leading zero in XML View. The problem is that I can not use Javascript for formatting when I use XML View.

The only solution that I found is to use a code like this:

```
<Text text="{path:'ZId', type:'sap.ui.model.odata.type.ODataType', oConstraints:{isDigitSequence: true}}" />
```

But I don't know why it does not remove the leading zeros while it has been said in its references:

`if true, the value is handled as a sequence of digits; while formatting leading zeros are removed from the value and while parsing the value is enhanced with leading zeros (if a maxLength constraint is given) or leading zeros are removed from the value (if no maxLength constraint is given); this constraint is supported since 1.35.0. To make this type behave as ABAP type NUMC, use oConstraints.isDigitSequence=true together with oConstraints.maxLength.`

The references that I found some related data were in the following links:

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3681816

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.type.String.html

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Integer.html

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are neither using the correct type implementation nor the correct binding syntax for setting the constraints. Please check the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.type.String.html):

```
<Text text="{
    path : 'ZId', 
    type : 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String', 
    constraints: { 
         isDigitSequence : true,
         maxLength : 10
    }
}"/>
```

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball and you don't provide any details. However, types are the intended and proven solution. But you can also use workarounds, up to you.

Comment: To be honest, nothing changes in the backend, and it returns String all times, but I think SAPUI5 runs the library that you used in some especial moment of time, and maybe loading data asynchronous causes this problem. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: The library I use? This is the build in functionality which is intended to be used in your use case and is used by thousands of applications.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for leading the zeros:

```
<ObjectNumber number="{= parseFloat(${ZId}) }"/>
```

or

```
<Text text="{= parseFloat(${ZId}) }"/>
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. It is interesting that we can call a JS function in XML View. But what is the role of that $? Can you explain what does it do?

Comment: The provided solution uses expression binding. (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html). While it is a great feature it does not make sense to misuse it in the described case.

Comment: So the $ provides path mechanism. "To embed a path containing a closing curly brace into an expression binding, use a complex binding syntax: ${path:'...'}. Example: "{:= ${path:'target>extensions/[${name} === \'semantics\']/value'} === 'email'}"."

Comment: The correct solution is to set the constraints of type string to "isDigitSequence : true" as in the next answer.